# Returning an error to an outbound message

Tags: workflow, soap, workflowoutboundmessage

In my app I provide users with a link to use in an Outbound Message which expects certain fields to be sent depending on what they said they would send during the configuration on my side.

On successful processing of the outbound message I return a success body like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
                <Ack>true</Ack>
           </notificationsResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Which works fine. My question is, is it possible to return an error message back to Salesforce so that it shows up in the Outbound Messages monitor?

For example, say the user in my configuration says they are going to send the Case ID, and the Contact ID, but when I receive the outbound message it didn't include the Contact ID. I'd like to return an error to Salesforce like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
                <Ack>Missing required field "Contact ID"</Ack>
           </notificationsResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

So that message shows up in the Delivery Status queue and the user can see what they did wrong, fix it, and retry sending.

Is that something that's possible to do?

Comment: My understanding was it's impossible, but it would be awesome to find out I'm wrong.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bpv4AAC

Comment: Also, Since the SessionID, which allows for a call-back into Salesforce without needing to authenticate first, can be sent with the SOAP message you can update the endpoint (if you own it) to call into SF using that session ID to write an error log

Comment: Outbound messages WSDL is implemented in a way that it can only response can only be either true or false. Or parsing exception

Comment: @Eric that sounds like a good idea. What exactly do you mean by "write an error log" though? Is there some sort of general log I can write to? (Sorry - my Salesforce knowledge isn't very high).

Comment: @GeneralKandalaft - No, you would have to create the object to hold the data...

Comment: Ah got it - that makes sense, thanks for the idea. At that point I could also just have a table on my side storing errors. The biggest issue is allowing the message to be replayed with new/modified data (sometimes it's just fixing up the config on my side and the message can stay the same - those cases would be fine).

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is no direct mechanism to return error messages in the notificationResponse for Outbound Messaging.

```
<element name="notificationsResponse">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="Ack" type="xsd:boolean" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element> //This section is the last in the types definition section.
```

Source - [Understanding the Outbound Messaging WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_wsdl.htm)

You can only use the Ack boolean in the response to return an ACK or NACK.

Voting for the idea [Logging and Notification on Errors in Outbound Messages](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bpv4AAC) might help in the long run.

---

The Notification will have an OutboundMessage Id element along with the sObject that triggered the notification.

As Eric commented, you could use this along with the SessionId and PartnerURL from the `notifications` to write a record back to Salesforce with the details of the failure. This could be to a field on the record in question, or to a dedicated error handling record.

You could, for instance, make a chatter post on the problem records in Salesforce to indicate what the problem was.

Comment: I've been playing around with this concept since reading Eric's comment. I like the chatter post idea. Better than a log record for us at least.

Comment: How would you use the boolean to send back a NACK / would that be for reporting a failure? It seems like the WSDL only supports an ack, and in other places I read, it seems like Salesforce just interprets a message as a NACK if the request times out.